# primefaces datatable edit (RowEditor) update in the database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i want to edit my datatable and update the mysql database. i'm using primefaces i edit datatable but it doesn't work.when i put just this :

```
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Annee Edited",""+((Annee) event.getObject()).getAnnee());  
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
```

the value in the datatable changes and i get the message Annee Edited. but when i add :

```
Annee anneee = anneeMetier.getAnnee(((Annee) event.getObject()).getAnnee());
anneeMetier.update(anneee);
```

it doesn't work, it don't change on the datatable nor in the database.
I'm using jsf, spring and hibernate. If someone could help with this, i'll appreciate it.

Annee.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form1">
            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
            <p:panel header="Sale Item" style="width: 400px;"> 
                <p:spacer height="30px;"/>
                <p:dataTable value="#{anneeBean.listeAnnees}" var="o"  widgetVar="50" style="width: 60px;" editable="true">
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{anneeBean.onEdit}" update=":form1:messages" />  
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{anneeBean.onCancel}" update=":form1:messages" /> 
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">  
                            <h:outputText value="Item Name" />  
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:cellEditor>  
                            <f:facet name="output">  
                                <h:outputText value="#{o.annee}" />  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <f:facet name="input">  
                                <p:inputText value="#{o.annee}" style="width:100%"/>  
                            </f:facet>  
                        </p:cellEditor> 
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">  
                        <p:rowEditor />  
                    </p:column> 
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

AnneeBean.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import model.services.AnneeMetier;
import net.vo.Annee;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("view")
public class AnneeBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int annee;
    @Autowired
    private AnneeMetier anneeMetier;
    private List<Annee> listeAnnees;

    public AnneeBean() {
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listeAnnees = anneeMetier.getAllAnnees();
    }

    public List<Annee> getListeAnnees() {
        return listeAnnees;
    }
    private AnneeBean(int annee) {
        this.annee=annee;
    }

    public int getAnnee() {
        return annee;
    }

    public void setAnnee(int annee) {
        this.annee = annee;
    }

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {  
        Annee anneee = anneeMetier.getAnnee(((Annee) event.getObject()).getAnnee());
        anneeMetier.update(anneee);

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Item Edited",""+((Annee) event.getObject()).getAnnee());  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
    }  

    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Item Cancelled");   
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
        //orderList.remove((Annee) event.getObject());
    }  
}
```

this my update method in business and in dao layers :
business

```
@Override
    public void update(Annee annee) {
        anneeDao.update(annee);
    }
```

dao :

```
 @Override
    public void update(Annee annee) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx=null;
        try
        {
            tx=session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(annee);
            tx.commit();
        }
         catch(RuntimeException e)
         {
           if(tx != null) 
            {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
         }
         finally
         {
            session.close();
         }
    }
```